# How to swap two asp.net controls in client side depend on situations?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my project I have a page as named `EduStandardCoursManager` that depend on type of query string which has sent to page show different reaction.
In `EduStandardCoursManager` we have two controls `(courseSelector,standardSelector)` that If query string sent `StandardID` I want to `StandardSelector` place 1st and `CourseSelector` place 2nd.
Like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="type" name="standardSelector" placeholder="StandardSelector" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="type" name="courseSelector" placeholder="CourseSelector" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And if query string sent `CourseID` I want to `CourseSelector` place 1st and `StandardSelector` place 2nd.
Like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="type" name="courseSelector" placeholder="CourseSelector" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="type" name="standardSelector" placeholder="StandardSelector" value="" />

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there any way to change these controls depend on query string type?
(I won't place 4 control instead)

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC with Razor views?

Comment: @Mads Taanquist - No

Comment: Use, for example, JavaScript for managing content on your page. You can write a directive that shows the content like you want it to depending on the value returned by the controller. There are many ways of managing views using JS based frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, change your HTML to add Id to your rows

```
<table>
    <tr id="courseSelectorRow">
        <td>
            Course<input type="text" name="courseSelector" placeholder="CourseSelector" value="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="standardSelectorRow">
        <td>
            Standard<input type="text" name="standardSelector" placeholder="StandardSelector" value="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And add this JavaScript snippet, you must have jQuery referenced in your page

```
<script>
    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    var standardID = getParameterByName('StandardID');
    if(standardID && standardID != '' )
    {
        $("#standardSelectorRow").insertBefore("#courseSelectorRow");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to put them in a panel and show the one you want according to the QueryString value OnLoad.

```
        <asp:Panel ID="StandardID" runat="server" Visible="false">

            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="type" name="standardSelector" placeholder="StandardSelector" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="type" name="courseSelector" placeholder="CourseSelector" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>

        <asp:Panel ID="CourseID" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="type" name="courseSelector" placeholder="CourseSelector" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="type" name="standardSelector" placeholder="StandardSelector" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
```

And here is the code behind:

```
    public string foobar;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["foo"] != null)
        {
            foobar = Request.QueryString["foo"];

            if (foobar == "CourseID")
            {
                StandardID.Visible = false;
                CourseID.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                StandardID.Visible = true;
                CourseID.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here are the results when you change the QueryString:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I want to swap controls. This solution doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Really?  It worked exactly as you asked when I ran it.  Your question is a presentation problem, not dynamic code writing.